# Convert solution to the latest version

Tags: visual-studio

I am practicing Microsoft net framework training kit. The problem is that the solution/projects were made by Visual Studio 2008. I use Visual Studio 2012.

The projects are unavailable.
[image]

I want to modify the solution file and project files. Just worry about messing up them.

Another snapshot:
[image: snapshot]

How to modify them by editor then I can load them with visual studio 2012?

Comment: Are the projects VB.NET and you do not have VB.NET installed, perhaps only C#, or vice versa? There should be no issue.

Comment: @Love Have you tried to open it in VS 2012? Maybe I'm wrong, but it should migrate your solution to 2012 automatically. If not, you can open it before in VS 2012, once migrated to 2010, you can open it in 2012 and it should work.

Comment: Yes, I tried in VS 2012. But it didn't migrate the solution to 2012 automatically. Just unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to 2010 first, then convert it to 2012. It is the particular case. It could be the project was written in 2008 but faied in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio should do update the projects and solutions for you. In my experience, it only shows unavailable when the project is located in a different location than where the solution file is looking for it. Perhaps you recently changed the name or copied only some of the files?

At the very least you should be able to remove the unavailable projects and re-add the original projects. They'll be converted as they're added.